# Cannot center text in canvas

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to center text in a canvas in a TextView subclass. It looks fine in Eclipse, but not in the device:

Eclipse:

[image]

Device:

[image]

There's a reason I want to center the text in this way. Which I'm not explaining here (and is also not in the code), since it doesn't belong to the problem.

I'm already using dips and sps.

The code:

```
package com.example.test2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CenterTest extends TextView {
    private Paint paint;
    private Paint paint2;
    private Rect bounds;

    public CenterTest(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CenterTest(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint2 = new Paint();
        bounds = new Rect();
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        //draw background
        paint2.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint2);

        //measure text
        paint.setTextSize(getTextSize());
        paint.getTextBounds(getText().toString(), 0, getText().toString().length(), bounds);
        int textWidth =  bounds.width();
        int textHeight =  bounds.height();

        //center before drawing text
        canvas.translate((width / 2) - (textWidth / 2), 0);
        canvas.translate(0, (height / 2) - (textHeight / 2));

        //let TextView.onDraw() do the rest
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    >
    <com.example.test2.CenterTest
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:text="label"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Maybe the reason is somewhere in TextView.onDraw() but that's more than 200 lines of code and I don't have time now... and not even sure if it's there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try to use android:gravity="center"

```
<com.example.test2.CenterTest
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:text="label"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Comment: No, I said that I wanted to center the other way.